# SQL left join with where clause to apply some conditions

Tags: sql, hsqldb

These are my tables(with some records):

```
Product:
ID PRICE NAME    DESCRIPTION
1  100   laptop  laptop_desc
2  200   mouse   mouse_desc
3  300   伊吾    伊吾伊吾

Product_Translations:
PID  LANG NAME DESCRIPTION
1    ch   伊吾  伊吾伊吾
```

And following is my query:

```
SELECT p.id,p.price,
      COALESCE(pt.Name, p.Name) name, 
      COALESCE(pt.Description, p.Description) description
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_T pt
ON pt.PID = p.ID 
AND pt.LANG = 'ch'  
WHERE  (UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%'))
```

I had thought that this would return 2 records(with ids 1 and 3), but it returned only one(one with id 3); I expected that the WHERE clause would be applied after JOIN is done.  However, If I give the query like the below it is working fine:

```
SELECT p.id,p.price,
      COALESCE(pt.Name, p.Name) Name, 
      COALESCE(pt.Description, p.Description) Description
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_T pt 
ON pt.PID = p.ID 
AND pt.LANG = 'ch'   
WHERE (UPPER(p.name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%') OR UPPER(pt.name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%'))
```

Why would I have to mention the condition for both the tables ? Can't I apply the where clause on the result after join is done ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  They are very different databases.  I am removing the database specific tags.  You can add the one you are really using.  Second, your first query should fail because `name` is in both tables and the column has no table reference.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No my first query didn't fail and I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: . . It is entirely unclear how the first gets parsed.  Which `name` does HSQLDB choose?  In any other database, this would generate an error.

Comment: Why down vote? If there is any mistake with the question, please comment and give me some time to at least update the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It chose the name from the first table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff HSQLDB has a setting `sql.enfore_refs` to generate an error with ambiguous usage. This is off by default.

Comment: Move WHERE clause's pt conditions to ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN behavior. (Now it's executing more as inner join...)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `COALESCE` function in the `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT p.id,p.price,
      COALESCE(pt.Name, p.Name) Name, 
      COALESCE(pt.Description, p.Description) Description
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_T pt 
ON pt.PID = p.ID 
AND pt.LANG = 'ch'   
WHERE UPPER(COALESCE(pt.Name, p.Name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you were assuming that the column alias "name" was being used within the WHERE clause. e.g. if I used the alias "name_name" instead

```
SELECT p.id,p.price,
      COALESCE(pt.Name, p.Name) name_name, 
      COALESCE(pt.Description, p.Description) description
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_T pt
ON pt.PID = p.ID 
AND pt.LANG = 'ch'  
WHERE  (UPPER(name_name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%'))
```

However the order of execution is different to the order of writing. The FROM & WHERE clauses are executed before the SELECT clause hence the column alias defined in the select clause does not exist when you are trying to use it.

FYI: This is the generic sequence of clause execution

```
FROM
   JOINs (as part of the from clause)
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT    << column aliases defined now
ORDER BY
```

also note it is due to this sequence that column aliases CAN be used in the ORDER BY clause

Your second query's where clause is what I would recommend, i.e.

```
WHERE (UPPER(p.name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%') OR UPPER(pt.name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%'))
```

as I prefer to avoid functions in the where clause for both performance and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE clause is applied after JOIN.
Result of your left join is the following:

```
ID PRICE NAME    DESCRIPTION PID LANG PNAME PDESCRIPTION
1  100   laptop  laptop_desc 1   ch   伊吾   伊吾伊吾
2  200   mouse   mouse_desc
3  300   伊吾    伊吾伊吾
```

So if you add OR condition for both tables you get two records, otherwise you get one.

Comment: No, result of the query without where class contains only id,price,name and description columns with 2 records.

Comment: It's a left join, where left table has 3 records, so join results in 3 records. Columns you wrote are only the ones you selected, I wrote all columns of both table to show theorical join result.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause is applied after the join but before the SELECT items, including the COALESCE functions, are chosen.

You want the query to return the two records with Chinese name or translation. The Chinese name is returned with `UPPER(p.name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%')` and the Chinese translation is returned with `UPPER(pt.name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%')`. So you do need the OR condition, otherwise only one row is returned.